# CUDA kernel not called by all blocks

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I got a strange behavior trying to run a simple vector addition.
If I run the code below using the printf function, everything runs fine and I got the expected result, 5050.

Now if I remove the printf function, only the first block is executed and I got 2080 which is the expected result for the sum up to 64.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**vecSum.cu:**

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 64

__global__
void vecSumKernel(int N, float *d_v, float *d_out)
{
    int idx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int t = threadIdx.x;

    printf("Processing block #: %i\n", blockIdx.x);

    __shared__ float partialSum[BLOCK_SIZE];
    if(idx < N)
        partialSum[t] = d_v[idx];
    else
        partialSum[t] = 0;


    for(unsigned int stride=1; stride < BLOCK_SIZE; stride *= 2)
    {
        __syncthreads();
        if(t % (2*stride) == 0)
            partialSum[t] += partialSum[t + stride];
    }

    __syncthreads();
    *d_out += partialSum[0];
}

void vecSum_wrapper(int N, float *v, float &out, cudaDeviceProp devProp)
{
    float *d_v;
    float *d_out;
    size_t size = N*sizeof(float);

    cudaMalloc(&d_v, size);
    cudaMalloc(&d_out, sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(d_v, v, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_out, &out, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int nbrBlocks = ceil((float)N / (float)BLOCK_SIZE);
    vecSumKernel<<<nbrBlocks, BLOCK_SIZE>>>(N, d_v, d_out);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(&out, d_out, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_v);
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
    ...

    int N = 100;

    float *vec = new float[N];

    for(int i=0; i < N; ++i)
        vec[i] = i + 1;

    std::chrono::time_point<timer> start = timer::now();

    float result = 0;
    vecSum_wrapper(N, vec, result, devProp);

    std::cout << "Operation executed in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<chrono>(timer::now() - start).count() << " ms \n";

    std::cout << "Result: " << result << '\n';

    delete[] vec;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may have some concurrency issue in the last line of your kernel. You want to try using atomicAdd for this.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET Looks like an answer to me, you might want to post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the last line of your kernel `*d_out += partialSum[0]` may expose some concurrency issues, as you surely know `__syncthreads` does not synchronize blocks.
[`atomicAdd`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) may solve this concurrency issue.

As for the reason why it works better with `printf`, I would assume that the printf requires some synchronization, hence blocks would not enter this last instruction at the same time, but I have Nothing to prove this.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I had to change a bit the last line though with a **if(t % BLOCK_SIZE == 0)** to prevent all threads to add the partialSum[0] to d_out and get a huge number. I think this may affect the performances also, to have some thread divergence like this... Maybe there is a better way to do that.

Comment: You may want to have a look at cooperative groups for gpu-wide synchronization - https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cooperative-groups - There is then a global sync, but data exchange shall take place in global memory.